# AppleScript: How to repeat a search for a file until it is found?

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm working on an automation that causes a secondary app to run a process on a file which is then copied into a source directory. Once the file is copied over into the directory I want the automation to continue.

If the original file was Blah.wav, the new file will be named Blah-leveled.wav

However, once the app is finished, the AppleScript still runs without moving on to the next step.

```
set folderPath to "Users:Seth3:Music:Podcast Automation"

tell application "Finder"
    repeat
        if (not (exists file ((folderPath) & "*-leveled.wav"))) then
            delay 10
        else
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

---

***Edit:*** Is there a way to get the script to repeat until any file within folderPath has "leveled" in its name? I tried

```
set folderPath to "Users:Seth3:Music:Podcast Automation"

tell application "Finder"
    repeat until (count (files of folderPath whose name extension is "wav")) = 2
        delay 6
    end repeat
end tell
```

but it gives me an error saying "Can’t get every file of "Users:Seth3:Music:Podcast Automation"."

(the =2 refers to the both the original and new files from the secondary app's process)

Comment: Are you intending that the asterisk serve as a wild-card character? If so, applescript doesn't work that way.

Comment: That was the intent, good to know it won't work like that.

Comment: You could try setting a variable to the basename part of the filename and then use that variable to build your string, e.g. `(folderPath & ":" & fName & "-leveled.wav")`. BTW, consider appending 'podcast automation' with a colon, which will implicitly tell the script that it is a folder. Then remove the '& ":"' from the above.

Comment: To determine whether a folder contains any files with a string in their name, try:`exists (files of folderPath whose name contains "leveled")`. Again, I would append a colon when setting folderPath. BTW, if you are adding files to the folder, you could try setting up a 'folder action', which could run a script whenever a file is added.

Comment: I figured it out! I ended up changing it from Finder to System Events, but used the line you put in your most recent one. I'll add it in an edit.

Comment: Actually, make it an answer and then accept it. That will make it easier for others to find. Glad you found your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mockman, I was able to resolve this. Here's the code I used.

```
set folderPath to "/Users/Seth3/Music/Podcast Automation/"

tell application "System Events"
    repeat until (exists (files of folder folderPath whose name contains "leveled"))
        delay 6
    end repeat
end tell
```